# SwiftUI - AVPlayer show controls when video didn't started yet

Tags: swiftui, avplayer

I have multiple videos inside LazyVStack and there are no controls before the videos is clicked, which makes it look like it's not a video but image.

When a playing video is clicked then it pauses and the controls are visible, why no also before the video plays?

I tried:

```
player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: vidUrl)!)
player!.pause()
```